# Good workflow for debugging the gitlab CI pipeline

Tags: gitlab, continuous-integration

I am currently setting up a test-build-deploy CICD pipeline in Gitlab.
My problem is that the development process is very painful since the feedback loop is so slow.

Right now I am setting up a job for the deploy stage so everytime I make a change (e.g. my last change to the pipeline was due to the fact I had set the protocol to http instead of https when pushing the built package to a repo) I have to re-run the whole pipeline since the deploy stage needs an artifact from the build stage.

Does anybody have some suggestions or resource pointers on how to improve this workflow? Is there e.g. a way of retrieving artifacts from a previous pipeline run to speed up the current run when only the last stage has seen changes in the pipeline configuration?

Thanks!